# Magento 2 getting error: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.1, php-5.6

While installing custom module at server i'm getting this error at frontend. My php version at server is 5.6. But same module at my localhost with php 7.0 version is working fine. I'm not able to understand this why this error showing. The error line code is below:

```
array(
    $this->_productVisibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
    $this->_productVisibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
);
```

Any single help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) The error message should specify a particular file and line. Include that line in your question, so we can actually help. (2) If this is a third-party extension, you should contact the creator.

Comment: Without the *full* error message and at least the line of code that causes it, this is guesswork. But a parse error suggests that this custom module probably requires PHP 7.

Comment: @fschmengler, In your comment you mentioned PHP 7. Can you explain little more about why php 7 need?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Guys i got solution of my own question. just **replace** below code

**array(
    $this->_productVisibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
    $this->_productVisibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
);**

**to**

**$this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());**

Now this code is compatible with PHP 5.6 as well as 7

Thanks for @Alan Storm for guiding me

Answer (score 8):

The code in your module is not PHP 5.6 compatible.  Consider the following program.

```
#File: test.php
<?php
class A
{
    public function foo(){
        $foo = array( 
            $this->_productVisibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH, 
            $this->_productVisibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
        );
    }
}
```

If you run this through PHP's standard lint scanner (in PHP 5.6)

```
$ php -l test.php
```

You'll end up with the following error

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `')'' in test.php on line 6
>   Errors parsing test.php

The problem is trying to access a class constant on an instance variable.

```
$this->_productVisibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH
```

This is invalid syntax in PHP 5.6.  Whomever wrote this code did not write it with PH 5.6 support in mind.

The right thing to do here?  Use a server with PHP 7.  PHP 5.6 [goes out of active support at the end of this year (2016)](http://php.net/supported-versions.php), and while it has 2 years left os security patch support, Magento runs much better with a PHP 7 enviornment.

If that's not possible, you'll need to fork the extension, and rewrite **all** the code in a PHP 5.6 compatible way, and reapply your changes whenever the extension updates.